# How to pass large data into service angular2

Tags: angular

I make data calls using data service between angular 2 and my MVC code

```
 this.DataService.add(id).subscribe((addLists:Project.Models.AddModel[]) => {
 this.addLists = addLists;
 });
```

I am sending 1 or more items as parameter to service in my data service file:

```
 add = (Id) => {
 return this.http.get("/site/getItems/getItems?id=" + Id)
            .map(this.getSuccess)
            .catch((e) => {
                if (console && console.log) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                return Observable.throw(e);
            });

};
```

and I am reading the values in my C# code like

```
[RoutePrefix("site/getItems")]
[NoCache]
public class AddController
{
   ... initialization code
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("getItems")]
   public IEnumerable<AddModel> GetItems(int id)
   {
    ....logic
   }
}
```

This works for few parameters. However, now I  need to send the entire model data consisting of rows and columns. 
How can I possibly achieve this?

Comment: Why not to use `post` for this?  `this.http.post("/site/getItems/getItems", complexData)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to use `post` instead becasue your url length is limited with 1024 symbols in IE so very big objects even serialized can be out of this size.

You client action can be

```
this.http.post("/site/getItems/getItems", complexData)
```

Your server action can be

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getItems")]
public IEnumerable<AddModel> GetItems(ComplexData data)
{
 ....logic
}
```

Comment: Can I not send more that one parameter here? I want to send this.http.post("/site/getItems/getItems", normal data1, normaldata2, complexData). it is giving me error if i am sending comma separated params like this in post?

Comment: no, only one. But you can combine your data into one object like `{ data1: normalData1, data2: normalData2, ... }`. And create ViewModel on server side to represent this object `class ItemViewModel { SomeObj1 data1, SomeObj2 data2 }`. So your action input parameter can be `GetItems(ItemViewModel data)`. This works for you?

Comment: I am sending only one variable (adjusted my code). However, i am getting error: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

Comment: I think based on your router settings your request should be `this.http.get("/site/getItems/getItems/" + Id)`. Not through query parameters.

Comment: No, the + makes the data pass as /[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]

Comment: Sorry, I can't get now how is your code looks like :) You use post as suggested? Or get? Because based on your exception - you have post on server but use get on client, or something else. Could you paste your code? Or you use code from answer?

Comment: I think there should be some change in the code this.DataService.add(id).subscribe((addLists:Project.Models.AddModel[]) => {
 this.addLists = addLists;
 });

Comment: Suggested solution does not help? `this.http.post("/site/getItems/getItems", complexData)` on client and `[HttpPost][Route("getItems")] public IEnumerable<AddModel> GetItems(ComplexData data)` on server?

Comment: It gives me error: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

Comment: Because you send `GET` from client. You need post. Please check your code.